# Open vim file with cursor on first search pattern match (similar to line no. with vim +N file)

Tags: regex, vim, vi

Is there a way I can open vi/vim with a given word ( or regex pattern) to match so that the cursor is on the first matched word ( regex pattern) after opening. Something similar to the line no. option

```
  vim +line_no file.txt
```

and I'm looking for something like

```
    vim /regex/ file.txt
```

This is helpful when I don't have the line no. handy and I can avoid `grep`ing the file to search it quickly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add a + to your "something like" and you have your answer -- `vim +/regex file.txt` is what you are looking for (remember to quote your regex to avoid shell from messing it up).

Check out `:help starting.txt` for more information.

Comment: This is an excellent answer...precisely what I've been looking for... a very clean/efficient way to deal with unstructured files...saved my day...thanks!

Comment: This is amazing